# Can't print a flash application within electron

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, electron, chromium

**My problem**

I am currently developing an electron (v4.2.10, I can't upgrade) application with the primary purpose of browsing on a specific homepage (using electron-navigation) and making their flash games playable. 
I have included the [Pepper Flashplayer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-pepper-flash-plugin) (v32.0.0.156) for this purpose and so far it is all working well.

However when trying to print a page including a flash game it will print a blank page. Trying the same in my current versions of Chrome or Firefox (with current flash player) yields the same result, however in Edge it works.

**What I've tried so far**

- I have no access to the actual pages of the site or any of the swf files
- The pages with the swf files are http (I tried setting browserWindow web preference disableWebSecurity to true, no change)
- I have tried different versions of the flashplayer
- Screenshotting the page is sadly not an option
- I have looked into the plugin [nw-flash-trust](https://github.com/szwacz/nw-flash-trust) but I am accessing an external source
- When I downgraded electron to v3.0 it actually managed to print most of the display, which may point to it being related to the underlying chromium version

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this? I have absolutely no knowledge of flash development itself. I would love to be able to print on v4.10 too. Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you got it working?